# Final Effective URL - PHP (Proxy)

Tags: php, proxy

I apologize in advance for my English. I have small problem. 
I want to get Final Effective URL from page

```
streamuj.tv/video/00e276bf5841bf77c8de?streamuj=original&authorize=ac13bb77d3d863ca362315b9b4dcdf3e
```

When you put a link into the browser gives me to .flv file 
But when I put it through PHP gives me `s3.streamuj.tv/unauthorized.flv`

When I try it through this: `getlinkinfo.com/info?link=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.streamuj.tv%2Fvideo%2F00e276bf5841bf77c8de%3Fstreamuj%3Doriginal%26authorize%3Dac13bb77d3d863ca362315b9b4dcdf3e&x=49&y=11`

So everything is fine indicates that

```
s4.streamuj.tv:8080/vid/d0fe77e1020b6414a16aa5316c759add/58aaf1dd/00e276bf5841bf77c8de_hd.flv?start=0
```

**My PHP CODE:**

```
<?php
session_start();
include "simple_html_dom.php";
$proxy = array("189.3.93.114:8080");
$proxyNum = 0;
$proxy = explode(':', $proxy[$proxyNum]);

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.streamuj.tv/video/00e276bf5841bf77c8de?streamuj=original&authorize=ac13bb77d3d863ca362315b9b4dcdf3e');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FILETIME, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy[0]);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT, $proxy[1]);
$header = curl_exec($curl);
$info = curl_getinfo($curl);
curl_close($curl); 

$u1 = $info['url'];
echo "u1: $u1</br>";
$u2 = str_replace("flv?start=0","flv",$u1);
echo $u2;
?>
```

Where is the problem? Why it makes unauthorized.flv?

Answer (score 0):

### Solution

Server was checking client legitimacy via `user-agent` HTTP header parameter.
Using custom `user-agent` solved the problem.

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array( 'user-agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2950.0 Iron Safari/537.36' ));
```

---

**Original post:**

> Most likely the generated flv URL is not pointing to static place. It
>   probably uses sessionID + cookie / verifies IP (one of these, or
>   both).
>
> Without knowing what header you have to request with via CURL, you
>   probably won't get a relevant response.

Comment: When you put a link into the browser so it works. When you put a link to http://getlinkinfo.com that it shows there, too. So it's crap verification IP.

Comment: @user3502252 You are right. I have tried personal Glype proxy on free hosting and it really returns flv.
Try using `curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PROXY, 'http://189.3.93.114:8080/');`and remove `CURLOPT_PROXYPORT`

Comment: example please..?

Comment: $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.streamuj.tv/video/00e276bf5841bf77c8de?streamuj=original&authorize=ac13bb77d3d863ca362315b9b4dcdf3e');
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FILETIME, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PROXY, '189.3.93.114:8080');
    $header = curl_exec($curl);
    $info = curl_getinfo($curl);
    curl_close($curl);

Comment: I am not sure if i understand. I have just quickly checked my own code in some project. My point is that curl with html proxy works just fine written on one line including port number rather than splitting it in two params.
`$proxy = "http://189.3.93.114:8080/";
.
.
.
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);
...`

Comment: Ah... Well then i guess it's back to what i have said. - It probably tries to authorize via given sessionID and some cookie token on redirect. Glype proxy PHP app manages this, curl on it's own does not. So what to do? **EDIT:** I have checked glype cookies, it doesn't store any cookies, try to set legit `user-agent` with curl call http header

Comment: `curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'user-agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2950.0 Iron Safari/537.36'
    ));`

Comment: @user3502252 if you could vote and set answer as solution i'd be grateful - with reputation over 50, i will be able to comment on other people's answers and questions.

Comment: @user3502252 I don't want to spam you, but please tick the answer as solution. - Having rep below 50 is somewhat frustrating, when i can't ask for details in comments and even when i'd need more information, i can interact only via answers.